# Using string-type resource identifiers in Windows .rc files / dlls

Tags: windows, winapi, dll, mfc

We have a number of MFC extension dlls in our code base, many of which have embedded Windows resources defined in the projects .rc files (IDS_..., IDD_..., IDB_... etc). We use **numerical identifiers** to define our resources, taking special care that our resource ids don't clash across dlls, which requires some management to ensure our developers don't use the same numberings.

I've realised that **string-type resource identifiers** might be an easy way to go, meaning that we can define unique identifiers for each resource in each different dll.

My question is, are there any technical problems with doing this, for example:

- Will the MFC dll / resource chain still function correctly?
- Will the Visual Studio resource editor still work?

I haven't found anything in the MS Technical Notes to say this would be a problem - I'd just wondering if people have had experience with this.

Comment: I was forgetting one thing when I wrote this question - dialog resource id values (IDD_...) must be integer identifiers to ensure proper functioning of the HtmlHelp(...) API with the HH_HELP_CONTEXT command (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms670088(v=VS.85).aspx)

Comment: Do you have any experience to share on this question? We are dealing with the same problem now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note however that IDs of strings in the string table (IDS_) MUST be numeric (16 bits IIRC). The difference between a string and another resource is due to strings not being individual resources. Actually, the string table consists in a set of resources, each containing up to 16 strings with consecutive IDs.

Same goes for Control IDs within dialogs. But you most likely know that.

In the resource editor, you can specify a string resource id in the property grid by simply putting quotes around the resource names.

Regarding dialogs and the resource editor: You'll have a minor problem: Whenever you create a class for the dialog, the generated code contains enum { IDD = resourceid }. Needless to say that it won't work for a string id. But you can easily get rid of this IDD enum and replace it by a string.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, particularly that regarding string table resources.